# Importing HTML5lib to Python35 Windows platform

Tags: python, html5lib

A search for html5lib reveals apparent installation with Path

C:\Users----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-
packages\bs4\builders_pycache_

However, import command returns the following

```
 import html5lib
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named 'html5lib'
```

I'm stumped. I have found similar issues addressed here, but no solutions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you could post the text of the error message (rather than only a link to a screenshot). If you like, you can indent the text by four spaces to create a code block.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand. Do I copy and paste the code, indenting four spaces to get the desired result?

Comment: Yes. Any line of text in a Stack Overflow post becomes part of a code block if you indent it by at least four spaces. You can also put text between backticks (`) to create an inline code block. Edit your post and try it out!

Comment: In general, Stack Overflow uses much the same rules and syntax as [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: A common problem is having multiple Python installations and your search PATH picking the wrong one. Check that.

Comment: That's probably not an installation path. The path suggests its some kind of cache file. Does `pip freeze` show it as installed?

Comment: I have installed and uninstalled two prior versions both were 3.5. But when I check, there is only one folder of Python 35-32.

Comment: `pip freeze` does not show it as installed but if I execute a `pip install` command it returns a syntaxerror.

Comment: Additionally, `python -m pip install html5lib` returns a SyntaxError.

Comment: Quit and restart the interpreter then `python -m pip install html5lib` works. The key observation is Python caches the module making it unavailable, the solution is to reset.

Comment: @arodwente It sounds like your entire Python and pip installation is corrupted. Uninstall Python. Delete its installation directory. Delete the C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\ directory. Now reinstall the latest Python and run `pip install html5lib`. (The latest installation should include pip out of the box; you might have to check it as an option during install, though.) Btw, you need to use the @ syntax for people to get notified of your messages.